# fetch user_profiles by avoiding N+1 query in graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `graphiql-ruby` gem for using graphql. I am trying to get the list of users with its userprofile and its company. However, it consumes more than 5 minutes and hits the api several times. It even crashes my server. Can anyone help me at this, please?

this is what i have done

```
module Queries
  module Users
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include GraphQL::Schema::Member::GraphQLTypeNames

    included do
      field :users, [Types::UserType], null: false
      field :user, Types::UserType, null: false do
        argument :id, ID, required: true
      end
      field :currentUser, Types::UserType, null: false
    end

    # Get all users list except admins
    def users
      User.where.not(roles: ['admin'])
      # context[:current_user].logs.info!('User Data Fetched') && user
    end

    def user(id:)
      User.find(id)
    end

    def current_user
      context[:current_user]
    end
  end
end


module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :email, String, null: false
    field :user_profile, Types::UserProfileType, null: false
    field :grants, [Types::GrantType], null: true
    field :companies, [Types::CompanyType], null: true
    field :my_companies_with_grants, [Types::CompanyGrantType], null: true

    def grants
      Grant.where(user_id: object.id)
    end

    def my_companies_with_grants
      current_user = User.find_by(id: object.id)
      company = current_user.companies
      userid = current_user.id
      company.map {|comp| { company: comp, grants: comp.get_user_grants(userid), company_id: comp.id } }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how i am querying for the list of users

```
query {
    employees: users {
      id
      email
      userProfile {
        ...UserProfile
      }
      roles
      createdAt
      companies {
        ...Company
      }
      grants {
        ...Grant
      }
    }
  }
  ${COMPANY}
  ${GRANT}
  ${USER_PROFILE}
```

why it is taking too long time to load all the users ? How can it be make efficient?

UPDATE

```
class ApiSchema < GraphQL::Schema
  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)

  use GraphQL::Batch
end
```

Record loader

```
class RecordLoader < GraphQL::Batch::Loader
  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

  def perform(ids)
    @model.where(id: ids).each { |record| fulfill(record.id, record) }
    ids.each { |id| fulfill(id, nil) unless fulfilled?(id) }
  end
end
```

I changed my user_type.rb and did the following for user_profile

```
 field :user_profile, [Types::UserProfileType, null: true], null: false do
      argument :id, [ID], required: true
 end



 def user_profile(ids:)
      RecordLoader.for(UserProfile).load_many(ids)
  end
```

But i get `"message":"Field 'userProfile' is missing required arguments: ids"` issue

I setup the `graphql-batch` but could not figure out where should i use RecordLoader as per the way I am using(types and resolvers)

Comment: How many Users, how many Grants are there?
Have you checked the log?

Most likely N+1 Queries.

Comment: it seems like N+1 query. There are more than 300 users and grants are also near to like that

Comment: I found graphql-batch gem but did not get idea on how to implement it.

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question about batch loading.

Comment: I think editing the same sounds good.